# Is there a way to change VoiceOver output channel?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, accessibility, voiceover

Is there a way (swift3/objc) to redirect output of VoiceOver between [headphones, speaker, BT, ...] ?

Because the API documentation as far as I could see doesn't have any information on channel changing...

We would like the ability to record voice while the user is listening to VoiceOver feedback on headphones (or change that, if they like).

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, all sound is routed to the default audio route to start, including VoiceOver. When a new audio route is connected (eg. Bluetooth headphones), two extra VoiceOver options become available. First, an "Destination" option appears  in the [VoiceOver rotor](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204783) that lets users choose the system's audio route. Second, the Sound section of VoiceOver settings in Settings app includes the option to select separate "Speech Channels" and "Sound Channels". You can even limit Speech output to a single channel of the route, which would let you listen to music in one ear and VoiceOver output in the other.

On Mac, this is a user-configurable setting within VoiceOver Utility.

You cannot redirect VoiceOver output programmatically on either platform. This is probably due to the catastrophic user experience that could create. Imagine redirecting your visual output to an unplugged device in your closet. How would you recover control of your computer?

[image: Screenshot of the Sound tab of VoiceOver Utility]

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I was actually asking for ios devices. Since you mention there is a possibility of "catastrophic" effect, ios devices might be under more vulnerability, I guess?

Comment: I missed that you tagged the question with iOS, my mistake. I'll edit my answer to clarify that and address your second question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use overrideOutputAudioPort in AVAudioSession to redirect the VoiceOver. Assuming your mode is set to playAndRecord.

Comment: That however seems to redirect all sound to the default audio output. So it seems impossible for now to direct voiceover to one channel and the real audio to another. Thanks anyway.